# Always get path starting /cygdrive from cygpath?

Tags: cygwin, cygpath

On Cygwin, the `cygpath` application translates between Windows and Unix-style paths.

Consider the following examples:

```
$ cygpath -u "c:/"
/cygdrive/c

$ cygpath -u "c:/cygwin64/bin"
/usr/bin
```

Is there any way to get `/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin` from the second command?

I need this because sometimes Cygwin gets confused about where its root is, so I want an absolute path in order to be clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Cygwin's `cygpath` doesn't support this.  The best you can do is manually fix it up with your own conversion tool; something along the lines of:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ "$1" == -z ]]; then
    # Invoked with -z, so skip normal cygpath processing and convert the path
    # here.
    #
    # The sed command replaces "c:" with "/cygdrive/c", and switches any
    # back slashes to forward slashes.
    shift
    printf "%s\n" "$*" | sed -r 's!(.):([\\\/].*)$!/cygdrive/\1\2!;s!\\!/!g'
else
    # Not invoked with -z, so just call cygpath with the arguments this script
    # was called with.
    exec cygpath "$@"
fi
```

If you store the above script as `mycygpath.sh` then it will behave exactly as `cygpath` does unless you give it the `-z` argument, in which case it will simply convert `n:/` to `/cygdrive/n/`:

```
$ ./mycygpath.sh -u "c:/"
/cygdrive/c

$ ./mycygpath.sh -u "c:/cygwin64/bin"
/usr/bin

$ ./mycygpath.sh -z "c:/cygwin64/bin"
/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin
```

Of course, there's the obvious question of *why* "Cygwin gets confused about where it root is"; that's not something that should happen at all and implies there's something wrong with your Cygwin setup. But that's not the question you asked and you've not given enough detail to be able to start making suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. The problem actually arises with users of my app -- they find it doesn't work by double-clicking on it (missing cygwin1.dll). This should be fixed by adding cygwin to the path, but some users fix it by dropping cygwin1.dll into the app directory, which does make the app run, but means none of cygwin's mounts are set up correctly.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. The other option would be for you to distribute cygwin1.dll with your app in the first place. Unless you're using the paid-for version, that comes with some GPL obligations, but they shouldn't be much more on top of the GPL obligations you already have by linking to cygwin1.dll.